# add style when user scrolls, remove it when user scrolls back to top

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a class I want to add a style to if a user scrolls down any amount, and I want to remove or add a different class if a user scrolls back up to the top. I am trying to give my nav background a color because its transparent when when the page loads, but the background would kick in if the user scrolls - so my sticky nav can show properly. I don't know if I should use javascript, or where that script should go on in my php to work - ?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my header code:

Toggle navigation
            
            
            
        
        
            ">"  height="height; ?>" width="width; ?>" alt=""/>

Here is what I have so far, placed the script in my :

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $(document).on('scroll', function (ev) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
      $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('.colored');
    } else {
      $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass('.colored');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

and here is my link: http://o-pd.com/tji16

I'm not able to get the class .colored to be added to .navbar-fixed-top's styles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on('scroll', function (ev) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
      $('your-element-selector').removeClass('foo');
    } else {
      $('your-element-selector').addClass('foo');
    }
  });
});
```

Edit: wrapped the code in $(function () {}) so it'll run when the document is ready.

Comment: Where should I place this script? In the <head>? After the nav code? Also, would I add the . for the class, or leave it out - 'your-element-selector' = '.navbar-fixed-top'? Or should I do 'navbar-fixed-top'?

Comment: I'm going to edit the script so it'll run when the document loads -- just a heads up. That way, you can put it in your head, or at the end of your `<body>` tag. And yes, you should add the dot for a class selector as usual. I was just using an easily-replaced string. :)

Comment: I edited the question with the code as I'm trying to add it but it still doesn't work - wondering if I'm missing something @ajpocus

Comment: @Noy gotcha, taking a look now.

Comment: @Noy you need to load jQuery before you load the script. Add the following script tag before the script I wrote: `<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @Noy that link is to jQuery 3.0. It doesn't support older versions of IE. If you need to be compatible with IE, use this script tag for jQuery 1.x: `<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: I added the script to load jQuery it but it still isn't working

Comment: @Noy you're calling `.addClass('.colored')`, but you should be calling `.addClass('colored')` (no dot) :)

Comment: @Noy you should only add a dot to the class when you're writing a selector for jQuery. When you add a class to an element, you just need the class name. I realize I told you to add a dot before, and I may not have been clear.

Comment: that was it @ajpocus - I can't thank you enough, appreciate your incredible help!

Comment: @Noy no problem! Happy to help! :)